# I'm trying to access my model but instead of the Html class I want to do it with a html5 input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @id = "fnTxtBox" })
```

Is there a way to access the model like above but using this instead?

```
    <input type="text"/>
```

I can't seem to find a way to direct the input to a target property and thus bind it...

Thanks!

Comment: Just add the `name` attribute to match the property name `<input type-"text" name="FirstName" ...>` (but why would forego all the benefits that html helpers give you?)

Comment: it worked thanks a lot! its for educational purposes :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't that just

```
<input type="text" id="fnTxtBox" name="fnTxtBox" value="@Model.FirstName"/>
```

But then you would need a `fnTxtBox` parameter on your POST method, instead of a model-type with a FirstName property.

**EDIT**
Or if the Model might be null:

```
<input type="text" id="fnTxtBox" name="fnTxtBox" 
                  value="@(Model == null ? "" : Model.FirstName)"/>
```

And if the Model never exists, you can leave out that `value` entirely.

Comment: @David I extended my answer